# Text to speech receiving many speak requests at once

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am writing an app that reads out strings one after the other.  My problem is that TTS seems to stutter through the first couple, say one properly and then stop.  I can't understand why.

```
    public void onInit(int status) {

    Log.d("TTS", "2");
    String text = desc;
    Toast.makeText(ct, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

This onInit method is located in a Broadcast Receiver so every time a proximity alert is received it reads the associated String. I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it can help you in your case or not,but I was facing problem like it gets requests to speak many time and hence it keeps on repeating the new strings and doesn't complete the previous one.So I did this trick.Hope it can help you for yours.:P

```
public void onInit(int status) {

    Log.d("TTS", "2");
    String text = desc;
    Toast.makeText(ct, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(!tts.isSpeaking())               
        tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);       
}
```

Comment: That's brill.  It stopped the stuttering for me.  Thanks so much.  It's not moving on to the next String though so I'll have to figure that out next.

Comment: what is the flow of your app? I mean,how you want to use TTS? I didn't get how you want TTS to speak various strings?

Comment: I have it adding a string to the intent for a proximity alert.  Once the proximity alert is fired that string is passed in and read out by TTS.  I discovered that some of the values are null and some are so I am a bit confused about it.

Comment: Ok.But sorry,there is no method which can check if TTS has completed speaking or not other than what i used in my answer.So cannot help you for this issue! :(

Comment: @Hiral there is a `UtteranceProgressListener` that knows how the TTS is doing.